# Why do I need a server with create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, single-page-application, create-react-app, serve

I recently created a website with create-react-app. Since this is not a web app, why do I need a server to see it? I tried to open the index file in build folder but it doesn't work unless I'm serving it from a server.

Comment: Look in the console.

Comment: [You don't](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment).

Comment: @FabianSchultz: That's still a server.

Comment: You need a server to provide the other static content in the build directory e.g. bundle.js, css files etc. If I open up the index file without a server (e.g. file:///<path to file>/index.html, it can't find the other files.

Comment: yeah but why? thats still static js code, why doesnt it load unless served by a server?

Comment: It's a path issue. In the test I just did it is search for the static folder in file:///static i.e. it has lost the route path of where the index.html file is located.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the homepage root url in the `package.json` file e.g.

```
{
   ...,
   "homepage":"file:///<path to build directory"
}
```

> npm run build

This will now find the static content in the build directory from the file system without a server.

Comment: Can you explain a little in detail about where to write ("homepage":"file:///<path to build directory") statement and how to give the path?

Comment: @PrakharMittal The original question was why can't you just open the index.html file in the build directory (produce by `npm run build`) with a browser and everything just work i.e. no server. This doesn't work because it tries to load the static files from the root of your file system. If you put the above homepage argument in the package.json file it will work. The path needs to be an absolute path to the build directory e.g. if you run `npm run build` in /home/prakhar/myproject, you would set homepage to /home/prakhar/myproject/build in your package.json.

Comment: @Martin. I tried giving the path as you suggested. But it still is not working for me.
I gave the paths as : 
"homepage":"build", 
"homepage":"/build", 
"homepage":"C:/Office/Prototype/build"  
But it was not under (dependencies or scripts). It was written independently.

Comment: this question needs more answers, how will I get the absolute path if my app is hosted on the server? you should mention that this will only work if you're running it on your local machine, if not, then you should not set the homepage argument since the hosting provider server will *serve* your ./build files for you.

Comment: It seems like that path doesn't have to be absolute. The absolute path worked for me, but the relative one also worked, i.e.
```"homepage":"./"```